# Azure same FTP url for all azure websites sharing same appservice plan

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I created few web applications for the one app service plan. For all these apps I am seeing one FTP url. Issue is that when I go to the URL, I can see one "Site/wwwroot" folder which only shows one application.

Isn't is possible to access FTP of other web applications?

All applications works fine. I don't understand how this FTP is being created. If it's showing just one application in FTP, what criteria is based on that? I am seeing the 1st application based on the alphabetical order.

[image: Application]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The FTP Url is same for all the sites in a stamp and will be same even if you create multiple app hosting plans as long as the hosting plans are in the same stamp. A stamp is a collection of servers and roles in a particular datacenter.

So how azure connects to the right site - the distinction here happens when you provide the user name for the site that you are trying to connect. The user name has the form sitename\$sitename when using publish credentials and has the form sitename\username when using deployment credentials and this name is used by app service to identify which site you are connecting to.

http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/azure-web-sites-ftp-credentials has more details.

Also read https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-credentials to understand difference between the two kind of credentials.

So just specify credentials in this way and you can connect to your sites using ftp.

Hope this helps

Comment: sitename\username, that makes sense. Browsing the files from VS server explorer seems mush easier that giving credentials and login to FTP if you just need to view files.