# FTP access to Azure websites - connecting to the wrong site

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-web-app-service, windows-explorer

I have about 6 different Azure websites all on the same subscription.
When I look at the FTP deployment address they all have the *same* address (ftp://waws-prod-ml1-001.ftp.azurewebsites.windows.net) but different usernames/passwords.
The problem is that at least using Windows explorer there appears to be NO way to access a second deployment once it's already remembered that I've connected to a previous one. I've tried editing the address to include the username (ftp://username:password@wasa....) but no luck, I've tried shutting down all explorer windows, clearing the credential cache etc. etc, but no dice - it still keeps connecting to whichever one I first authenticated with at least since I last logged into Windows.
Does this basically mean I'll have to use a different FTP client that doesn't cache credentials like this? Bit surprised I can't find any forum posts suggesting other people haven't had this issue.

Comment: I can't speak to Windows Explorer, but I've never seen that problem with standalone ftp tools. In any case: off-topic for StackOverflow. This sounds like a Windows-specific issue that you might want to bring up on SuperUser.

Comment: It's a problem a developer who's deploying to multiple azure websites is likely to have, even if it's not strictly a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always right click in Windows Explorer and choose **Login As** option which will allow you to use a different set of credentials. 
[image]

To understand how FTP credentials work for Azure App Service, check out [Azure same FTP url for all azure websites sharing same appservice plan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37314901/azure-same-ftp-url-for-all-azure-websites-sharing-same-appservice-plan/37319194#37319194)